# Trying to make a drop down menu and can't get it to stay down after I hover onto an option

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to doing anything with code and I haven't had a lot of luck with finding the solution to my issue. I'm trying to make a drop down menu option but the menu closes as soon as I try to move my mouse to the other options. I seems to be working when I use the run option here so if anyone has any idea on what i'm doing wrong on the site please let me know! thank you!

> site is https://hntrsvg.cargo.site/ btw

> Heres the HTML & CSS (i'm using cargo collective for the site)

```css
<style>


  
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 8px 16px rgba(15, 206, 131, 1);
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content, dropdown-content:hover {
  display: block;
}

</style>
```

```html
<div class="dropdown" grid-col="x11" grid-pad="2">
<h2><a href="#" rel="home_page">GALLERY</a></h2>

<div class="dropdown-content">
  
  <p></p><h2><a href="Comic-Home-Page" rel="comics">COMICS</a></h2>
  <p></p><h2><a href="Illustrations" rel="comics">ILLUSTRATIONS</a> </h2>
 
 </div>

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured it out! Turns out my line spacing was making it so that there was a huge gap between everything and that caused the issue!